# symfony2 fosUserBundle add field with data from entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to add a "select" field on the login form with data from an entity.

My question is can I do it with fosUserBundle or do I have to remove fosUserBundle because I really need both but I don't see I to do it.

Override the registration is quite simple but I think it's more complex with the login form.

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented. I guess you're gonna need to override the login template, you can learn how to do that here : 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

You'll probably want to implement some custom login logic as well, which can be done by overriding default controller, this is documented here :
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

Comment: Good read ! I forgot that you'll probably need to customize the form class, here's the doc : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Comment: Thanks but this one is the RegistrationFormType  but what is the file for the login

Comment: Ah that's right there isn't any Form type for login, I guess all you need to do is to override `login.html.twig` and `loginAction()` in `SecurityController.php`